# Is this route of a airforce jet on flightradar faked?

Tags: flightradar24, indian-air-force

While looking at the flight routes of Indian airforce jets on flightradar, I have noticed that the trainee jets show a very weird flight pattern. Here's an example,

[image: Trainee Jet flight pattern]

The width of this screenshot is around 20KM. I don't think a jet can take such sharp turns. If so, why are these turns so sharp? Is this data somehow been faked, or is this issue with the radar?

Comment: You should click on airplane, and get the information from there. IIRC the last field is important (the "radar"): you can get more information on which kind of data is used. These look like MLAT, so user triangulation, which do no requires precise timing, so you get such weird lines

Comment: This is what happens with linear interpolation. But it is more honest, you can really see the data and resolution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, that has not been faked.

Flightradar is updated with a low frequency (from that screenshot I'd estimate once per 10 seconds, maybe more). This is done to reduce the computational demands on both the service that sends the radar info to Flightradar, and on the Flightradar servers.

Each dot in the track is one position update, and the website software just draws straight lines between them, which results in sharp corners. The real flight path will have a radius.